# Printing string in plot, spaces appear between characters

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a figure with pyplot in which a string is printed, with each character put in the x position of its index in the string.
I am saving the figure as a pdf, but somehow spaces are added between some characters.

Here's a minimal code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

string = ("QWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM")

plt.xlim(0,len(string))

for index, letter in enumerate(string):
    plt.text(index, .5, letter)

plt.savefig("fig.pdf")
```

If I run the code, in the final pdf there's a space between the first and second letter (Q and W), between the third and fourth (E and R) and so on.

Anyone has an idea of why this is happening and how I could avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously an `I` is much less wide than a `W`. So spacings are different. If you want to distribute those spacing more equally, consider center aligning the letters

```
plt.text(index, .5, letter, ha="center")
```

Also, consider using a monospace font, i.e. a font where each letter is equal in width, e.g.

```
plt.text(index, .5, letter, ha="center", 
         fontproperties=FontProperties(family='Consolas'))
```

[image]

Comment: With space I mean an actual space character, not just "space between letters". In both your case I still get space characters between letters. When using the monospace font there's even one space between each character.

What I mean is that, if I open the file ad copy the text, I get something like this:

Q WE R T Z U I O P A S D F G H J K L Y X C V B N M

As you can see, there are some space characters (for example between Q and W) that are not present in the initial string.

Comment: The text is not a single text, but 26 individual texts. How those individual texts are copied to the clipboard is steered by the application you use for copying. For example when using Foxit pdf reader, the copied text is `Q W E R T Z U I O P A S D F G H J K L Y X C V B N M` as expected.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then there's nothing much I can do, right?

Comment: I don't now what the ultimate aim is here. Why not create a single text in matplotlib?

Comment: I want to later have a second line (say at y = .6), where there is an asterisk at the x of some characters of the text string, so that these characters are highlighted. For this reason I think it's important to have each character printed at a defined x position. Ideally, the final pdf should be "searchable", meaning that I can search for substrings and should find them (which is now prevented by the space characters).

Comment: Maybe a stupid idea: If you place an additional text in the plot, which contains the whole string, and make this white (on white background) it should be searchable?